# Need to Append rows to Google Sheet in C#, getting "Stream was not readable" error

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So I'm trying to work through this tutorial for appending rows to a Google Sheet: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append

I got my "credentials.json" file from an earlier tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/dotnet#step_3_set_up_the_sample

I also used that second tutorial to create the scope, but I changed the parameter from "SpreadsheetsReadonly" to "Spreadsheets":

```
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };
static string ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart";
```

I also used the second tutorial to reference my "credentials.json" file, but I changed the FileMode and FileAccess parameters to "Append" and "Write":

```
UserCredential credential;

using (var stream =
    new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
...
    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
}
```

**Problem:** When I run the program, this is the error I get:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Stream was not readable.'

Through debugging, I have narrowed the problem down to the following line:

```
new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
```

When I change it to:

```
new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
```

or any of the other "FileMode.foo" configurations, I get no exception, and as expected, a window pops up to ask me for permission for the Google Sheets API to access my sheets.

So what's the deal? Is there some setting I need to enable to allow incoming requests to append rows to the sheets?

---

This is my full code:

```
using System;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Data = Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
using System.Threading;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
class Program
{
    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
    static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
    static string ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart";

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SheetsService sheetsService = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = GetCredential(),
            ApplicationName = "Google-SheetsSample/0.1",
        });

        // The ID of the spreadsheet to update.
        string spreadsheetId = "3m83oibDdSiufaFA8Gba-f8afsonasiofafo3J-9UDe4";  // changed

        // The A1 notation of a range to search for a logical table of data.
        // Values will be appended after the last row of the table.
        string range = "A2:A5";  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

        // How the input data should be interpreted.
        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum valueInputOption = (SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum)0;  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

        // How the input data should be inserted.
        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.InsertDataOptionEnum insertDataOption = (SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.InsertDataOptionEnum)0;  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

        // TODO: Assign values to desired properties of `requestBody`:
        Data.ValueRange requestBody = new Data.ValueRange();

        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest request = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(requestBody, spreadsheetId, range);
        request.ValueInputOption = valueInputOption;
        request.InsertDataOption = insertDataOption;

        // To execute asynchronously in an async method, replace `request.Execute()` as shown:
        Data.AppendValuesResponse response = request.Execute();
        // Data.AppendValuesResponse response = await request.ExecuteAsync();

        // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
    }

    public static UserCredential GetCredential()
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
            // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
            string credPath = "token.json";
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        return credential;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're confused. The `FileMode` value here has nothing to do with appending to a Google Sheet. It's opening `credentials.json`; you don't want to append to that file. You want to read it (`GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream)`) so `FileMode.Open` is correct.

Comment: @madreflection Ah, I'm missing the ol' forest again. Thanks!